# Google Chrome extension: for loop to assign chrome.tabs.create functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

I want to have a list of links, that each open a different Youtube video that has been predefined in links.xml. This file works perfectly, and all the links are generated, but whenever I click on **any** of them it opens a new tab with the URL of the **last** link in the list. What am I doing wrong?

```
<style>
body { width:550px; }
</style>

<script>
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "links.xml");
req.onload = showLinks;
req.send(null);

function showLinks() {
  var links = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("link");
  var p, a, h, t;

  for (var i = 0, link; link = links[i]; i++) {
    p = document.createElement("p");
    a = document.createElement("a");
    h = link.getAttribute("http");
    t = link.getAttribute("title");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode((i+1) + ') '));
    a.href = h;
    a.onclick = function() { chrome.tabs.create( { url: h } ); }
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(t));
    p.appendChild(a);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if there any other errors in your code, but it seems that you need to use closures, check this link: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed! I'm not sure how to mark this as answered so I'll just leave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacevillain was correct:

> it seems that you need to use
>   closures, check this link:
>   http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62